# SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody from CGPath polygon issue

Tags: cgpath

I'm having trouble drawing an SKPhysicsBody with a polygonal shape that's supposed to look like a halfpipe. The code I've got is as follows:

```
    _halfpipe_left = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"halfpipe_left"];
    _halfpipe_left.position = CGPointMake(5*26, 5*26);
    _halfpipe_left.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    CGMutablePathRef halfpipe_leftpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 78, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 78, 78);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 52, 78);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 48, 59);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 42, 47);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 31, 36);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 19, 30);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(halfpipe_leftpath, NULL, 0, 26);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(halfpipe_leftpath);

    _halfpipe_left.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:halfpipe_leftpath];
```

When I try and get the body to interact with others, it behaves as if there has been some much smaller, out of shape polygon created instead.

Any insight or help is much appreciated!

Comment: For anyone out there wondering, I found the answer. SKPhysicsBodies must be convex shapes, and this is concave.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the physics debugger created by Thomas Zinnbauer.

https://github.com/ymc-thzi/physicsDebugger

Its a great tool for debugging physics bodies, as it draws their shape on the sprites.